# How to call gs.listdir() with arguments on GAE, to list a bucket on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

According to the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions), [gs.listdir()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/functions#listdir) on Google App Engine may be called with some optional arguments, as shown in the included example...

```
files.gs.listdir('/gs/mybucket',prefix='/mysubdir/backups', max_keys=20)
```

However, when I try to call it with anything more than the plain Google Cloud Storage path alone (which works just fine), I get errors like this...

```
TypeError: listdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'
```

As requested, here's the traceback...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 710, in __call__
        handler.get(*groups)
    File "/base/data/home/apps/s~foo/1.361822114540385125/app_main.py", line 123, in get
        test = files.gs.listdir( '/gs/bar', prefix = '/folder' )
TypeError: listdir() got an unexpected keyword argument 'prefix'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you post the code instead of the example?

Comment: `class TestHandler( webapp.RequestHandler ):  
    def get( self ):  
        from google.appengine.api import files  
  
        bdir = files.gs.listdir( '/gs/my-bucket', prefix = '/folder' )  
        self.response.out.write( bdir )`

Comment: Sorry for this mess... my browsers edit-field is killing me... :-(  This is the important part  `files.gs.listdir( '/gs/my-bucket', prefix = '/folder' )`

Comment: Can you post the traceback of the error? are you running this on the dev appserver?

Comment: @SebastianKreft This is running on App Engine in the cloud, not local dev-server... Traceback: `File "/base/python_runtime/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 710, in __call__ handler.get(*groups)`

Comment: I can reproduce it, can you try running `files.listdir` instead.

Comment: @SebastianKreft Just using `files.listdir()` as you suggested, seems to work fine... Thanks! So the docs are wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that is a bug in app engine doc.

It should be doc for files.listdir, not files.gs.listdir.

files.listdir accepts arbitrary keyword arguments, files.gs.listdir accepts a single dictionary of keyword arguments. Hence the type error.

So please use files.listdir in the way documented. The bug will be fixed ASAP.

Thank you.

Comment: FYI: this bug is fixed now, current version of gsutil is 3.42

Comment: The correct import statement for this method is `from google.appengine.api import files` as described in [API documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlestorage/#before_you_begin).